# Spring security context path resolver

Tags: tomcat, grails, spring-security

I want to define the path of the session cookie, which is set from spring security, in order to allow multiple logins from the web-app. E.g:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/context1/login
http://localhost:8080/myApp/context2/login
http://localhost:8080/myApp/context3/login
...
```

Basically this is possible by overwriting `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`, `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`, `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, `SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler`. However I cannot find a handler, which is responsible for setting the cookie context-path, which I need to overwrite from:

```
/myApp
```

to the apropriate equivalent:

```
/myApp/context1
```

This is needed, in order to allow parallel logins to these Apps.

Q: How to change the cookie's path for session cookie (HttpSession) dynamically for tomcat?

Comment: I'm afraid you want to achieve something that can be easily done without tinkering with session. Your problem looks more like authorization and not authentication. Maybe you need to use roles for each context? Or access control list?

Comment: For concurrent authentication and allowing users to have multiple sessions wouldn't it be enough to configure ConcurrentSessionFilter and set maximumSession property to -1 to allow unlimited sessions in the ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy?

Comment: @Ravi: possibly, can you work out it a bit? how will the cookie be distinguished between folders?

Comment: @crudolf, but why do you need to distinguish the cookie path. Please provide your requirement on what you are trying to achieve for a better solution.

Comment: Maybe the approach illustred in [this thread (last answer)][1] is what you want?!


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/401574/tomcat-session-managment-independent-session-in-one-host

Comment: Please put an answer with a direct link. You get the bounty. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok... this time I think I have found what you are looking for. Look at [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/401574/tomcat-session-managment-independent-session-in-one-host)

I think you can do it in grails creating a [filter](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters)

Answer (score 2):

Your application container is responsible for sending session cookies to clients. 
Inside Spring Security code you will only see lines like this:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

There is no session-cookie-creation logic inside Spring Security source code. That's why there are no interfaces to implement or configuration attributes  to provide custom paths.

To specify path that will be assigned to any session cookies created by your web application you can put:

```
<web-app>
    <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <path></path>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

in your `web.xml` descriptor.

However you want to have many sessions in one web application.
Why don't you deploy new application for each user context? It's the most logical approach.

Edit:
I'm afraid you want to achieve something that can be easily done without tinkering with session. Your problem looks more like authorization and not authentication. Maybe you need to use roles for each context? Or access control lists?

Comment: To answer your question: Because there is a dynamic number of contexts.

Comment: So I guess there are not too many places, where session is created. Obviously I can set the path by hand by calling some methods in `HttpSession`. Is it doable to patch spring security for this?

Comment: There is no such method in `HttpSession`. I'm afraid you would need to get all cookies. Find cookie with name `JSESSIONID`. Clone it. Set your context related path to cloned cookie. For former cookie set `maxAge` to `0` (delete it). And finally add both cookies to response (former is deleted thanks to setting its `maxAge` to `0`). This is dirty. Study Tomcat/your container documentation. Maybe there is some vendor way to do it without dirty hacks?

Answer (score 0):

By default bean rememberMeServices of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.html)
is responsable for setting the cookie

Comment: Will this also be responsible for creating the HttpSession?

Answer (score 0):

Extend InlineExplodedTomcatServer

```
package myapp

    import org.grails.plugins.tomcat.InlineExplodedTomcatServer
    import org.grails.plugins.tomcat.TomcatLoader
    import grails.util.GrailsNameUtils
    import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector
    import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat
    import org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol
    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.lifecycle.ShutdownOperations
    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder
    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginUtils
    import static grails.build.logging.GrailsConsole.instance as CONSOLE
    import org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner
    import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils


    class MyappInlineExplodedTomcatServer extends InlineExplodedTomcatServer {

        MyappInlineExplodedTomcatServer(String basedir, String webXml, String contextPath, ClassLoader classLoader) {
            super(basedir, webXml, contextPath, classLoader)
            context.setSessionCookieDomain(System.getProperty('mydomain.com'))
            context.setSessionCookiePath('/mypath')     
        }

    }
```

Extend tomcat server factory

```
package myapp

import grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer

import org.grails.plugins.tomcat.TomcatServerFactory

class MyappServerFactory extends TomcatServerFactory {

    EmbeddableServer createInline(String basedir, String webXml, String contextPath, ClassLoader classLoader) {             
        new MyappInlineExplodedTomcatServer(basedir, webXml, contextPath, classLoader)      
    }

}
```

In events.groovy set the server factory

```
eventRunAppStart = {
        System.setProperty 'grails.server.factory','myapp.MyappServerFactory'
        }
}
```

Obviosly this configuration is applyed only when running with grails "run-app" and not when you deploy on tomcat or other server. On tomcat you have to configure it in tomcat configurations files

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have the cookie be dynamical either `/mypath` or `/mypath1`.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer default behavior of [successfulAuthentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#successfulAuthentication%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20org.springframework.security.core.Authentication%29) in spring security.

**Update(pointer from comment):** on successful authentication in the 2 point, spring security  `"Invokes the configured SessionAuthenticationStrategy to handle any session-related behaviour"`. So, try implementing custom `SessionControlStrategy` extending framework provided classes for your application, see if it fulfills your need.
Framework provided strategy classes are [ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.html), [NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy.html), [SessionFixationProtectionStrategy](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/SessionFixationProtectionStrategy.html)

---

**To control cookie creation logic after successful authentication and its values:**

1) Choose Remember me services for your application 
for example:
[TokenBasedRememberMeServices](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.html) or [PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.html)

2) Create a custom class `MyAppTokenBasedRemenberMeServices` extending the chosen Class for example: [TokenBasedRememberMeServices](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.html)

3) Override the method `protected void setCookie(String[] tokens, int maxAge, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)`. Its responsible for creating a cookie and adds the created cookie to the response (This way you can control any cookie value for e.g. context-path value). This method resides in Class: [AbstractRememberMeServices](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/AbstractRememberMeServices.html)

4) Map newly created custom class for `rememberMeServices`

I hope this helps!

Comment: I think the first link is very good indeed. However 1-4 is only useful for the persistent logged-in cookie (remember me cookie), but I need the session cookie.

Comment: @crudolf - would you like to set value(s) while session gets created? i.e. `HttpSession` value(s)

Comment: @crudolf - As a workaround, you can implement `HttpSessionListener`. This way `sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se)` method receives the notification of session creation. Then manipulate your application `HttpSession` values.

Comment: Sounds good, is it possible to overwrite the path of the cookie in this listener?

Comment: @crudolf - I have verified the `HttpSessionEvent` approach, it didn't work as expected; because session is already created before successful Authentication. So event is not getting raised.  I have updated post with `SessionControlStrategy` information. Please see if that helps.

Comment: I try it using SessionControlStrategy. I give feedback. Thanks