# How login to spring security using Ext.Ajax?

Tags: ajax, extjs, authentication, spring-security

I'm developing an application using Extjs-6 with Spring 4. My Application is Restful.
I enable CORS Origin as follow:

```
public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final String ORIGIN = "Origin";


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "10");

        String reqHead = request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers");

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(reqHead)) {
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", reqHead);
        }

        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            try {
                response.getWriter().print("OK");
                response.getWriter().flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else{
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
 }
```

Filter config:

```
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    ...
    <sec:custom-filter ref="CorsFilter" before="HEADERS_FILTER"/>
</security:http>
```

And the Bean:

```
<bean id="CorsFilter" class="..." />
```

I want to users loging with an AJAX request. I test ajax request using [**Advanced REST client**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/reviews?hl=en-US&utm_source=ARC) and [**http requester**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httprequester/?src=ss). Results of extensions are as follow:

[image]

[image]

Ext Ajax request code is as follow:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "http://localhost/Calk/j_spring_security_check",
//      params: {
//          "j_username": "ali",
//          "j_password": "123456"
//      },
    params: "j_username=ali&j_password=123456",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    method: "POST",
    success: function(){...},
    failure: function(){...}
});
```

When I send the request, it get `200 OK`, and I init the application in client side, And send some requests to get some data. But server for all this requests get `401 Unauthorized`.

**Whats the problem**?

**Important Update**:

Logining request is as follow:

[image]

**Server set cookie in response, and getting authorized data request is as follow**:

[image]

**Why**?

Comment: Did you try with `params: form.getValues()`?

Comment: yes, result is as above.

Comment: The problem is that the Request Method "OPTIONS" is used, which is always sent without the parameters you require for authentication. [Check here why that method is used](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?95656-how-to-disable-Ajax.request-method-quot-OPTIONS-quot&p=452480&viewfull=1#post452480).

Comment: Read the linked forum thread to the end. You can't have finished it in about 2 minutes.

Comment: The problem is not answered

Comment: The session cookie is restricted to `/Calk/` path, is your page with ajax located under this path? Inspect your ajax call, see what cookie is being set the first time in the response header, and whether it is being sent back in the second request header.

Comment: My page and my application are in different path. Page: `localhost/Calk` and Application: `localhost:8084/Calk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spring Security works as follows**:
If any request coming from a client have no JSessionID cookie, Spring will reset that client's session and set an invalid session for it.Then the next request will be sent with that invalid session.

So you need to set cookie in all of the Ext ajax requests. I guess some concurrent ajax requests do not send cookie.
In order to set cookie in all of ajax requests, you can add this event:

```
Ext.Ajax.on("beforerequest",function(con){
  con.setUseDefaultXhrHeader(false);
  con.setWithCredentials(true);
}
```

This function runs before sending all your ajax requests.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your error is you are making a cross domain request. I think your javascript application is running in different port while your application server is running on 8084.

For this to work you need to enable CORS support for your application. Here is how you can do that.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

[Follow this link](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) for detailed explanation. For the most part this should work for you, if spring-security is still complaning then you may need to add filter for spring security. You can do that by [following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26487792/319604)

```
public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final String ORIGIN = "Origin";


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (request.getHeader(ORIGIN) == null || request.getHeader(ORIGIN).equals("null")) {
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "10");

            String reqHead = request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers");

            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(reqHead)) {
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", reqHead);
            }
        }
        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            try {
                response.getWriter().print("OK");
                response.getWriter().flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else{
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
 }
```

Configure the Filter for Security

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" .... >
    ...
    //your other configs
    <sec:custom-filter ref="corsFilter" before="HEADERS_FILTER"/>
</security:http>
```

Expose the Filter as Bean

```
<bean id="corsFilter" class="<<location of the CORS filter class>>" />
```

Comment: I have some stores that all of them get data from same web server I set CORS config and it get all data correctly. But only Login request don't work correctly

Comment: Then try the Security Filter, Updated the Answer.

Comment: I updated my code according to your response. When I send Login Ajax Request, Server get `200 OK`(when I send incorrect user/pass, it get `401 Authorized`). When user Login successfully, page get some data usign ajax, But in next request server get `401 Authorized`.

Comment: Hmm it may be because it is creating a new session. Can you confirm.. if the session is same for both the login request and when you are sending data request ?

Comment: I don't know. But when I use http requester application work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the session cookie is being set for `/Calk/` path while the ajax call is made from `/Workspace/Calk/`. So you need to find where session cookie path is configured in Spring and change it to be just `/`.

I haven't used Spring security, but from a quick search [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755499/how-to-change-jsessionid-cookie-path-to-server-root-in-spring-app-on-jetty) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13687311/20128) questions seem to suggest that you can change the path in `web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
    <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <path>/</path>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```