# Cookie not set correctly in Extjs Ajax request

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs6, setcookie

I'm developing an [**Extjs-6**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0) application. My server application is RestFul. I have to login with Ajax. I send an Ajax request as follow:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({

   url: 'localhost:8084/Calk/j_spring_security_check',
   params: {j_username: 'ali', j_password: '123456',
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   },
   success: ...,
   faiulure: ...,
});
```

**Result of the request is as follow**:
[image]

After client receive `200 OK`, it read a store as follow:

```
Ext.define('Calk.store.Calk', {
   extend: '...',
   model: '...',
   proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url: 'localhost:8084/Calk/calk/all',
      withCredentials: true,
      useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
      reader: ...,
      method: 'POST'
});
```

**But result is as follow**:
[image]

**Why cookie set wrong**? **How Can I Fix it**?

Comment: The cookie is restricted to `localhost/Calk/` path, you are making ajax call from `localhost/Workspace/Calk/` url, the original cookie is not visible here. Make your backend to not apply restrictions on the cookie path.

Comment: I'm using java in backend. I've asked a question at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594371) and I start 100 bounty 2 days ago. I become happy if you contribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the following lines in Ext config:

```
Ext.Ajax.on("beforerequest",function(con){
  con.setUseDefaultXhrHeader(false);
  con.setWithCredentials(true);
});
```

So all of ajax requests will send cookie.